# Encoding issue during reading excel file in Python

Tags: python, json, excel, pandas, encoding

I use `read_excel` from pandas library to read excel content and convert it to JSON. I am struggling with encoding issue. Non english characters are encoded like `"u652f\u63f4\u8cc7\u8a0a"`.
How can I resolve this issue?
I tried

```
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(excel_filePath, encoding_override='ISO-8859-1')
new_data = pd.read_excel(wb)
```

Also

```
with open(excel_filePath, mode="r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
  new_data = pd.read_excel(excel_filePath)
```

I tried this code with encodings like: `utf-8, utf-16, utf-16, latin1...`

Comment: Will you please send the result of `print(new_data.head().to_dict())` if you can? I want to see the way the Chinese characters look in the dataframe's structure.

Comment: "\u652f\u63f4\u8cc7\u8a0a" is not corrupt. It's '支援資訊'.

Comment: You really need to provide a [mcve], but note, you state that you convert to JSON, in which case, Unicode escape is often used (to avoid ambiguity), which might be causing what you are seeing.

Comment: Can you show a snippet of your excel file? Even just the text of the cells that are producing this error so that we can also reproduce your error would work

Comment: I created an Excel file containing some of the non-english characters you mentioned  such as `支援資訊`, and I was able to load it with the single line:  `new_data = pd.read_excel(excel_filePath)`. What version of pandas are you using?

Comment: Are you seeing those characters in your final JSON? If so, what's your **_output_** encoding?

Comment: @ZachYoung, these characters are displayed in final JSON.

Comment: @richardec all characters are displayed well in data frame, no encoding problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the docs of the `json` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#character-encodings):

> The RFC requires that JSON be represented using either UTF-8, UTF-16, or UTF-32, with UTF-8 being the recommended default for maximum interoperability.
>
> As permitted, though not required, by the RFC, this module’s serializer sets `ensure_ascii=True` by default, thus escaping the output so that the resulting strings only contain ASCII characters.

Maybe surprising that in this day-and-age the module defaults to escaping non-ASCII (probably for backwards compatibility), so just override that behavior with `ensure_ascii=false`:

```py
with open(json_filePath, 'w') as f:
    json.dump(new_json, f, ensure_ascii=False)
```